# count comma-delimited values and get sum of another

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables; users and opinions. Sample schema and data below

```
users table
---------------------------------
userid
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5

opinions table
---------------------------------
opinionid   |   points   |   yes   |   no
    1             5         1,2,3      4,5
    2             5         1,3,5      2,4
    3            10         1,2,4      3,5
    4            10         1,4,5      2,3
    5            15           1      2,3,4,5

* the yes and no columns contains comma-delimited userids
```

desired result: group by userid, orderby points, yes, no

```
userid   |   points   |   yes   |   no
  1            45          5         0
  4            20          2         3
  2            15          2         3
  5            15          2         3
  3            10          2         3

Summary: for each userid, sum(points), count(yes), count(no)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You know what we're going to say, right?

Comment: OK. Normalize your data.

Comment: @badboy Why are you storing a comma-separated list of values?  This is going to make it much more difficult for you to query the data for the result that you want now or any of querying of the `yes`/`no` columns.

Comment: Can you please explain how the `sum(points)` should be calculated?

Comment: will the query be quicker when each userid has its own row in the opinionid? thanks for the help.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal if a userid appears on the yes column, the points are added to the user

Comment: Just add the UserOpinion table with columns UserId, OpinionId, YesNo

Comment: Strawberry, bluefeet, Mahmoud Gamal, Janne Matikainen thanks for the help! i will seriously consider normalizing my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [***normalize***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data, instead of storing values as comma separated, this will be easier to deal with in the queries. Just add a new column `user_id` as a foreign key , and a column as a flag `YesOrNo`, then for each opinion enter the users id's and for each set a flag value 0 or 1.

---

For now, you can use the [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function to do what you are looking for, like this:

```
SELECT
  userid,
  sum(CASE WHEN type = 'yes' THEN points ELSE 0 END), 
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Yes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS No
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    o.opinionid,
    o.points,
    'yes' AS type,
    u.userid
  FROM options AS o
  INNER JOIN users AS u ON FIND_IN_SET(u.userid, o.yes) <> 0
  UNION
  SELECT
    o.opinionid,
    o.points,
    'no' AS type,
    u.userid
  FROM options AS o
  INNER JOIN users AS u ON FIND_IN_SET(u.userid, o.no) <> 0
) AS t
GROUP BY userid;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d68f/18)

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple and elegant solution

```
    select userid, 
    sum(if(FIND_IN_SET(userid, yes.yes)>0, yes.points, null)) as points, 
    count(if(FIND_IN_SET(userid, yes.yes)>0,1,null)) as yes, 
    count(if(FIND_IN_SET(userid, yes.no)>0,1,null)) as no

        from users 
        left join opinions as yes 
        on (FIND_IN_SET(userid, yes.yes)>0 or FIND_IN_SET(userid, yes.no)>0)
    group by userid
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I haven;t yet but I will try this solution as well.

Comment: np. It will work faster than using subqueries, and speed is essential when working with strings.

Comment: your query seems not returning the expected output : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/486e5/16

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT yestbl.userid, total, yes, no
FROM
(SELECT userid,
SUM(oyes.points) total,
COUNT(FIND_IN_SET(u.userid,oyes.`yes`)) as `yes`
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
opinions oyes
ON FIND_IN_SET(u.userid,oyes.`yes`)
GROUP BY userid) yestbl
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT userid,
COUNT(FIND_IN_SET(u.userid,ono.`no`)) as `no`
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
opinions ono
ON FIND_IN_SET(u.userid,ono.`no`)
GROUP BY userid) notbl
ON yestbl.userid = notbl.userid
GROUP BY yestbl.userid
ORDER BY total desc;
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/486e5/28)**